# Cook's distance for GLM

Tags: self-study, logistic, cooks-distance

In Applied Logistic Regression by Hosmer, Lemeshow and Sturdivant (2013), the formula for Cook's distance in a logistic regression is given as,
$$\Delta\beta_j = \frac{r_{sj}^2h_j}{1-h_j}$$
where $r_{sj}$ is the (internally) studentised residual for observation $j$, and $h$ is the leverage value. However, in R I believe the Cook's distance for logistic regressions is adjusted by the number of parameters, $p$, in the model (including the intercept), i.e.
$$\frac{r_{sj}^2h_j}{p(1-h_j)}$$
Could someone confirm which is the correct version and why there is a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The original, 1977 paper by Cook](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Enchristo/statistics100C/1268249.pdf), scales the distance measure by dividing by $p$, defined as the rank of the design matrix, **X**.  The first formula you are citing above is not Cook's original distance measure, per se, but is [the measure proposed by Pregibon in 1981](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-9/issue-4/Logistic-Regression-Diagnostics/10.1214/aos/1176345513.full).

The second formula you provide is simply scaled by$\frac{1}{p}$, a constant—unless the deletion of an observation reduces the rank of the design matrix—so they are essentially the same measure, only scaled differently.  Since one uses the measure relative to all the other "Cook" $D_i$-type observations, or alternatively, a sensibly chosen cutoff value (which in itself is a source of much debate), the scaling shouldn't matter since all $D_i$ are scaled the same.  In other words, you're never really going to be examining a single Cook's value by itself.  Again, assuming $p$ is not reduced by deletion of the $i$th observation when computing the influence statistics, $p$ is constant, and all values will be scaled by $\frac{1}{p}$, so one shouldn't get caught up in the addition (or removal) of $p$ from the denominator when working with data of full rank.  Just keep in mind if you're selecting a cut-off value to be used with the distance statistic, $\frac{1}{p}$ needs to be taken into account so the appropriate cut-off value is adjusted accordingly.